# Ebay api, VerifyAddItem is returning errors when i send it xml using cURL

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am having trouble debugging this error i am recieving.
I tested the xml on the ebay developing site to see if it is valid and I recieved no errors
 However when I attempt to send the xml file I receive an error.

PHP code:

```
function EbayVerifyAddItem($search)
{
    $url= utf8_encode("https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll");  //end point
    $xmlrequest = temp/xmlfile.xml; // link to xml file
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlrequest);
    echo"<h3>Ebay Get Category</h3>";
    echo "URL: ".$url."<br>";

    $headers =  array(
    'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL: 901',
    'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME: productionDeveloperKey',
    'X-EBAY-API-SITEID: 3',
    'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: VerifyAddItem',
    'Content-Type: text/xml');

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);    // set headers using $headers array
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);              // POST request type
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml); // set the body of the POST
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    // return values as a string, not to std out
    $content=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 

    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "Path to xml file: ".$xmlrequest."<br>"; 
    echo printf("content: %s",$content); 
    echo "<br><br>";

    return true;
}
```

xmlfile.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VerifyAddItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
  <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
  <Item>
    <Title>Title</Title>
    <Description>Description</Description>
    <PrimaryCategory>
      <CategoryID>377</CategoryID>
    </PrimaryCategory>
    <StartPrice>1.00</StartPrice>
    <CategoryMappingAllowed>true</CategoryMappingAllowed>
    <ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>
    <Country>GB</Country>
    <Currency>GBP</Currency>
    <DispatchTimeMax>3</DispatchTimeMax>
    <ListingDuration>Days_7</ListingDuration>
    <ListingType>Chinese</ListingType>
    <PaymentMethods>PayPal</PaymentMethods>
    <PayPalEmailAddress>email@email.com</PayPalEmailAddress>
    <PictureDetails>
      <PictureURL>http://i1.sandbox.ebayimg.com/03/i/00/6b/63/03_1.JPG?set_id=8800005007 </PictureURL>
    </PictureDetails>
    <PostalCode>postcode</PostalCode>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <ShippingDetails>
      <ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>
      <ShippingServiceOptions>
        <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
        <ShippingService>UK_RoyalMailSecondClassRecorded</ShippingService>
        <ShippingServiceCost>2.50</ShippingServiceCost>
      </ShippingServiceOptions>
    </ShippingDetails>
    <Site>UK</Site>
  </Item>
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>Token String Here</eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
</VerifyAddItemRequest>
```

Error I receive:

```
Ebay Get Category
URL: https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll



Path to xml file: functions/tmp/Test.xml
content: 2015-08-15 21:00:07 100121SeriousError00RequestError 51SeriousError00RequestError 100111SeriousError00RequestError 100111SeriousError00RequestError 1115
```

Can anyone shed any light on where i am going wrong. If I can verify that the item will be successfully listed, I can go onto filling other details and list the item.

Comment: Would it be possible to see the output xml properly formatted rather than a vardump as it would be easier to read the error codes. From looking at [eBay's Error Codes](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/Errors/ErrorMessages.htm#ErrorsByNumber) my best guess it that the category number is incorrect.

Comment: I generated the xml using, $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
and have, $xml->formatOutput = true; so this is how the xml comes out. Otherwise: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> is on line 1 and the rest of the xml is on line 2

Comment: sorry missread your comment. I'll do a printf of it :-)

Comment: Could you add: `echo '<textarea>' . $xml . '</textarea>';` to your code just to make sure you're reading in the XML correctly.

Comment: I think the problem is that you're using simple_xml_loadfile which returns an object. You probably just want to read the xml by using file_get_contents instead - `$xml = file_get_contents($xmlrequest);`

Comment: Ok, Ill change it and try that, i added your code and it is coming up blank.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87070/discussion-between-tomyates-and-ben-jay-hutton).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're loading in your XML file as a PHP Object rather than a string. Instead of using the `simple_xml_loadfile` function which returns an object, use `file_get_contents` to read the xml file into the $xml variable:

```
$xml = file_get_contents($xmlrequest);
```

Comment: ??? Why haven't `asXML()` made it? How is it bad to turn it into an object while that would also verify the response is *well-formed-XML*? Especially as this is about error handling of the API? `file_get_contents` does less here, it does not check for well-formed XML for example and you couldn't read- out API error codes later on that easily. Not that you find problems where there aren't any :)

Comment: I have a function that generates the xml supplied above and make sure it is properly formated before it gets to this stage. But it would be prudent to check it again before passing it onto the ebay api. I've looked at your answer and will certinly add it to my code and see if it works fine :)

Answer (score 2):

> I am having trouble debugging this error i am recieving.

The "error" you see is the XML without the tags as the browser filters them. You have to look into the source (view source feature in your browser) or encode it properly or even parse it already as XML and obtain the error information from it (makes most sense as you're using an API).

Most likely important information about the error got lost that way. Most prominent still seems:

```
SeriousError00RequestError51
```

For which no concrete error information can be obtained in [the vendors documentation about the error codes](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/errors/errormessages.htm) (which specifies nearly all error codes), which shows you already prevented yourself so far to give a clear picture of the error.

However most likely your problem is you have not understood that you need to pass XML as string to the service endpoint.

While you verify the file contains valid XML by using an XML parser (which is good!), you miss to pass the XML as string to the webservice:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
```

As `$xml` is not a string but a [**SimpleXMLElement**](http://php.net/class.simplexmlelement) (which would effectively trigger `$xml->__toString()` which return text-content and not the whole XML) the correct form would be to use the [`SimpleXMLElement::asXML()` method](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.asxml) on it:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml->asXML());
```

And that's it already.

Comment: Very intriguing I never thought of it this way,  I'll see about changing my code to incorperate this into it ^_^

Comment: You're welcome. You could do the same with the response, as it's XML it's best parsed with an XML parser. You might want to improve error handling while loading the document thought: http://php.net/simplexml.examples-errors